# how to revise the iteration in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
global y
y=random.randint(1,99)
global guess
x=5
c=0
while(x>0):
    guess=eval(input("guess a number from 1 to 99:"))
    if(guess<y):
        win=False
        x=x-1
        print("guess is low") 
        c=c+1
        print("you have",str(x),"other chances")
        guess=int(input("enter a number from 1 to 99:"))

# Here it says again "enter a number from 1 to 99:".
# I want to get rid of this error.
# Can you tell me where am i wrong and what should i do?

elif(guess>y):
    win=False
    x=x-1
    print("guess is high") 
    c=c+1
    print("you have",str(x),"other chances")
    guess=int(input("enter a number from 1 to 99:"))
else:
    print("you guessed it")
    win=True
    break
    if(win):
     print("you won")
    else:
     print("your are a loser")
```

[image]

I have entered the code above and the statement "guess a number" repeats again but as you see
at the next level it should compare it with `y`.
what is the problem?

```
 another problem is that finally it prints"you have 0 other chances."
```

Comment: Stop using `eval`. You don't want to evaluate an arbitrary Python expression; you want to convert a string to an `int`.

Comment: Just delete all the `guess=int(input("enter a number from 1 to 99:"))` lines except the first one?

Comment: What does the output look like?Does it not output anything except `enter a number from 1 to 99:`? If so, your `if` statement must be misindented, and you're running a loop like `while flag: guess=eval(input("guess a number from 1 to 99:"))`

Comment: @ForceBru no it output rest of the code but it iterate that statement twice

Comment: @Nima_Eb, please post the full input and the corresponding output

Comment: @ForceBru i added the picture into my code

Comment: Well, Python does exactly what you told it to do: at the end of the `elif(guess>y):` clause it asks you for input, then gets back to the beginning of the loop and executes `guess=eval(input("guess a number from 1 to 99:"))`, which asks you for input once again. There's nothing wrong here

Comment: thank u for your guidance but another problem is that finally it prints"you have 0 other chances."

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot going on here, so I'm going to start by answering your question, with my revised code at the end. Any code I reference will be from your code.

The logic flow is accurate. Computers (unfortunately) only do exactly what we tell them to do. So, what did the above code tell the computer to do? I suggest learning to use a debugger or use `print()` statements to in-line debug your variables.

Starting off, `x=5`. Moving into the `while` comparison, `5>0` so that passes. The player inputs a value into `guess`, which is then compared against `y` (the hidden number). For both too high and too low, the guesses remaining (`x`) is decremented by 1, and then printed. So, starting off, first round, `x` prints as 4, because it is `5-1`.

Moving to the next round, `x=4`, `4>0` so the comparison passes. Input another wrong guess, and the guesses remaining decrements, and prints. The end of the second round has `x=3`.

This repeats until `x=1` at the `while` comparison. Input another wrong guess, `x=x-1` so `x=0`, and then `you have 0 other chances` is printed. This happens because going into the while loop, `x>0` evaluates as true, but the decrement occurs after that evaluation. One solution is to set the `while` condition 1 higher. Another is to include a comparison within that checks for that one edge case.

Below is my revised code. I've added comments, and edited to be a slimmed down, best/better practice code sample. Feel free to ask any questions, and point out any errors - just trying to give back to the community where I can.

```py
import random
y=random.randint(1,99)
guess=-1 #this is less than the possible range for `y`. 
x=5
c=0
win=False #declare this earlier, can compare in while conditional
while(x>0 and not win): # added `not win` to say 'as long as they haven't won'
    guess=int(input("guess a number from 1 to 99:")) #don't use eval, just cast to int
    if (guess!=y):
        x-=1 #reduce the number of guesses remaining
        c+=1
        if(guess<y):
            print("guess is low")
        else: #guess isn't y, and it isn't low, so must be high
            print("guess is high")
        if(x>0): #no guessses remaining, don't print this
            #print once at the end of each round except the last
            print("you have",str(x),"other chances")
    else: #guess == y, so they won!
        win=True
if(win):
    print("you won")
else:
    print("your are a loser")
```